# epoll возвращает событие с нулевым fd, почему так?

Tags: linux, c

Приведу весь код. вроде ничего не менял. но вчера и так далее всё работало. а сейчас пробую и epoll возвращает events с нулевым fd. и из-за этого я не могу прочитать данные. так бы можно было узнать, подключен ли клиент к серверу или какие то данные отправил. вот код.

```
/*
 * server.c - server for game.
 * author: Naidolinskii Dmitrii
 *******************************/
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "db.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "events.h"

/* сокет сервера */
static int sockfd;
extern struct conf conf;
struct sockaddr_in in_server;
int epollfd, nfds;
#define AUTH_ADMIN            0
#define AUTH_GAMER            1
char sym[2] = { '!', '1' };

#define DEFAULT_SIZE_POLL        65535
#define DEFAULT_SIZE_DATA         1024

struct epoll_event ev, events[DEFAULT_SIZE_POLL];

static void *thread_control_clients ( void *data ) {

    while ( 1 ) {
        nfds = epoll_wait ( epollfd, events, DEFAULT_SIZE_POLL, -1 );
        if ( nfds == 0 ) continue;
        if ( nfds == -1 ) {
            perror ( "epoll" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < nfds; i++ ) {
            char data[DEFAULT_SIZE_DATA + 1];
            int ret;
            printf ( "! %d\n", events[i].data.fd );
            ret = read ( events[i].data.fd, data, DEFAULT_SIZE_DATA );
            printf ( "nfds: %d ret: %d\n", nfds, ret );
            if ( ret <= 0 ) {
                char *byte = (char *) events[i].data.ptr;
                if ( byte ) {
                    if ( *byte == sym[AUTH_GAMER] ) db_offline_user ( events[i].data.fd );
                }
                epoll_ctl ( epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, &events[i] );
                /* здесь отправить другому игроку о том что игрок вышел из боя, если проводится бой.
                 * либо игрок вышел из игры ( клиента ). подключение закрыто.
                 */
                close ( events[i].data.fd );
                printf ( "клиент %d отключен.\n", events[i].data.fd );
                continue;
            }
            switch ( data[0] ) {
                case '!':
                    {
                        int ret = db_register_admin ( &data[1] );
                        switch ( ret ) {
                            case EVENT_EVENT_FALSE:
                                /* можно вывести сообщение об ошибке */
                                write ( events[i].data.fd, "false", 6 );
                                epoll_ctl ( epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, &events[i] );
                                close ( events[i].data.fd );
                                break;
                            default:
                                {
                                    events[i].data.ptr = &sym[AUTH_ADMIN];
                                    write ( events[i].data.fd, "!", 2 );
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case '0':
                    {
                        printf ( "регистрация пользователя. %d\n", events[i].data.fd );
                        int ret = db_registration ( &data[1], events[i].data.fd );
                        switch ( ret ) {
                            case EVENT_USER_IS_ONLINE:
                                /* отправить сообщение что пользователь онлайн
                                 * оборвать соединение */
                                epoll_ctl ( epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, &events[i] );
                                close ( events[i].data.fd );
                                printf ( "пользователь уже есть в игре %d\n", events[i].data.fd );
                                continue;
                                break;
                            case EVENT_EVENT_FALSE:
                                /* неправильные данные */
                                printf ( "неправильные данные.\n" );
                                epoll_ctl ( epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, events[i].data.fd, &events[i] );
                                close ( events[i].data.fd );
                                break;
                            default:
                                {
                                    events[i].data.ptr = &sym[AUTH_GAMER];
                                    write ( events[i].data.fd, "1", 2 );
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* создание потока */
void create_thread ( ) {
    epollfd = epoll_create1 ( 0 );
    if ( epollfd == -1 ) {
        perror ( "epoll_create" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create ( &t, NULL, thread_control_clients, NULL );
}

void wait_client ( ) {
    socklen_t soss = sizeof ( in_server );
    int client = accept ( sockfd, ( struct sockaddr * ) &in_server, &soss );
    if ( client == -1 ) return;
    printf ( "%d подключен.\n", client );
    ev.events = EPOLLIN;
    ev.data.fd = client;
    ev.data.ptr = NULL;
    if ( epoll_ctl ( epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, client, &ev ) == -1 ) {
        perror ( "epoll_ctl" );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}

/* конфигурация сокета */
void configure_socket ( ) {
     sockfd = socket ( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
     if ( sockfd == -1 ) {
         perror ( "socket" );
         exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
     } 

     int ret;
     {
        int opt = 1;
        ret = setsockopt ( sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof ( opt ) );
        if ( ret == -1 ) {
            perror ( "sock opt SO_REUSEPORT" );
            exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
     }

     in_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
     in_server.sin_port = htons ( conf.port );
     in_server.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
     ret = bind ( sockfd, ( struct sockaddr *) &in_server, sizeof ( in_server ) );
     if ( ret == -1 ) {
         perror ( "bind" );
         exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
     }
     ret = listen ( sockfd, conf.listen );
     if ( ret == -1 ) {
         perror ( "listen" );
         exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct epoll_event ev` имеет такой вид.

```
typedef union epoll_data
{
  void *ptr;
  int fd;
  uint32_t u32;
  uint64_t u64;
} epoll_data_t;

struct epoll_event
{
  uint32_t events;      /* Epoll events */
  epoll_data_t data;    /* User data variable */
} __EPOLL_PACKED;
```

я назначал сначала `fd` нужный дескриптор, а потом присваивал NULL для `ptr`. Так как это union, то я обнулял дескриптор с помощью ptr.
Решением будет убрать обнуление ptr.